# Angular add HTML element to dynamically created HTML element

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I have dropdown with items lets say.

```
<customDropdown>
   <item label="ITEM1"></item>
   <item label="ITEM2"></item>
   <item label="ITEM3"></item>
</customDropdown>
```

This dropdown created new div with class for each item. Problem is that I need to add button to items but because is custom dropdown I can pass value only through label which is string. Basically I need to do something like
`<item label="<button>DELETE</button>ITEM1></item>"`
But I cant because its automatically converted to string.

Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: Can you show the code of the customDropdown?

Comment: yes please share your code from customDropwon component.. without i would suggest if there is no other way than string make a switch case with the label and append the button

Answer (score 0):

which library are you using? its not possible to pass html element through attribute like that. if your library allows you to do such thing its either using `<ng-content>` ( and if that is the case your implementation would be : `<item> <button> delete </button> </item>`) or using custom templates.